# C# - How do I build/debug this code in VS2015?

Tags: c#, parsing, text, visual-studio-2015

I was given some code for a simple text file parser that I would like to build on and modify. It was built in VS and I've installed VS2015 Community so that I can work with it, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to set it up in VS2015.

A snippet of the very beginning of the code is below. Do I build it as a class, or a console application, or something else?  How can I modify it to read a local file line by line?

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public static class Cawk
{
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> Execute(StreamReader input)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    string line;
    //string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    //read all rows
    while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
```

Comment: Well you need a class, which you already have - if you intend to reuse this code in other projects make it a class library and test it with a unit test or console app.  Other than that it's not clear where you're stuck.

Comment: was your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you posted is a class file definition.

You will need a class called Cawk.cs with that code inside.

To run it, you will need something to invoke it, either a console app or a unit test will do.

For a console app:

- create a new console application project.
- add a new class named Cawk.cs with your code inside.
- in the 'program.cs' class (created when you create the console project), inside the Main method, call your Execute method.

To debug it, put a breakpoint on a line and press F5.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you've never build an application in visual studio, the easiest way are:

1. Start VS
2. Create new project: File -> New -> Project
3. Select Templates -> Visual C# -> "Console application"
4. Choose a folder to save the project, click OK.

That will give you a basic console application with one file Program.cs that has static method Main() inside. Now let's add the new class.

5. Right click the solution tree, choose Add -> New item
6. Choose "Class", enter name "Cawk", click OK.

You will create a new file "Cawk.cs" for Cawk class. Let's fill it up.

7. Copy-paste your snippet in Cawk.cs, overwriting it's contents.
8. Correct the namespace - it should be the same as in the Program.cs

So it will become something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public static class Cawk
{
...
```

9. Now you can call Cawk.Execute() static method from the Main() method.

Comment: Thank you, @enkryptor!  I'm almost there.  Built as you suggested and calling Cawk.Execute() from Program.cs.  Only one error - "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'input' of 'Cawk.Execute(StreamReader)' --- I guess it's looking for the input file.  Can I just give it a path like Cawk.Execute(C:\temp\file.txt)?

Comment: I've answered you with another post. If it helps, a vote up wouldn't be a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

The method Execute() accepts a [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) object. This object reads data from a **byte stream** - a flow of data coming from some kind of source - user input, file, another application, etc.

In order to parse a file through Cawk you need to instantiate StreamReader first with a [proper constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx), and dispose it afterwards (see "**using**" statement in C#).

Let me provide you an example of code:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\temp\file.txt"))
{
    var results = Cawk.Execute(sr);
    foreach (item in results)
    {
        // do something with item which is Dictionary<string, object>
    }
}
```